# Trouble accessing python superclass attributes

Tags: python, inheritance

I have two classes that loosely take the form below:

```
class Foo:

    def __init__(self, foo):
        self.__foo = foo


class Bar(Foo):

    def bar(self):
        print self.__foo
```

When I try to invoke the `bar` method on an instance of `Bar`, it fails.

```
b = Bar('foobar')    
b.bar()
```

Result:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "foobar.py", line 14, in <module>
    b.bar()
  File "foobar.py", line 10, in bar
    print self.__foo
AttributeError: Bar instance has no attribute '_Bar__foo'
```

My understanding is that this code should work based on [two](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8377634/python-accessing-superclass-attributes) [other](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4608968/how-to-access-a-superclasss-class-attributes-in-python/4609078) questions, why doesn't it?

Comment: @MartijnPieters The linked-to question definitely provides a compatible answer but I don't think I would have known where to look without first knowing the answer!

Comment: Don't worry, I didn't expect you to. If closed as a duplicate, your post serves as a sign-post to the other question, so that in future anyone searching for the same problem may find it more easily.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Agreed. That's why it received my close-vote as well.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Simple. `__foo` contains 2 underscores in the beginning, so it's assumed to be class-private method and it's transformed into `_Classname__method`.

When you request access to the attribute named as such on `Bar` object it asks `Bar` class if it has this method (not `Foo` class), so `self.__foo` is always the same as `self._Bar__foo`.

From the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3.3/reference/expressions.html#atom-identifiers):

> When an identifier that textually occurs in a class definition begins
>   with two or more underscore characters and does not end in two or more
>   underscores, it is considered a private name of that class. Private
>   names are transformed to a longer form before code is generated for
>   them. The transformation inserts the class name, with leading
>   underscores removed and a single underscore inserted, in front of the
>   name. For example, the identifier __spam occurring in a class named
>   Ham will be transformed to _Ham__spam.

If you modify your code slightly

```
class Foo:
    def __init__(self, foo):
        self.__foo = foo
        assert hasattr(self, '_Foo__foo'), 'Attribute has been just created'


class Bar(Foo):
    def bar(self):
        assert hasattr(self, '_Foo__foo'), 'No errors, thanks to inheritance'
```

`assert` statements will not cause any `AssertionError`s.

Add `__getattribute__` method to `Bar` class to capture all requests to `Bar` objects:

```
class Bar(Foo):

    def bar(self):
        print('Accessing __foo from bar')
        print(self.__foo)

    def __getattribute__(self, name):
        print('Requested', name)
        return super().__getattribute__(name)

b = Bar('foobar')
b.bar()
```

There will be 3 lines (apart from `AttributeError`) in the output:

```
Requested bar
Accessing __foo from bar
Requested _Bar__foo # AttributeError follows
```

As you can see, if attribute you are requesting has 2 leading underscores, Python is renaming it on the fly.

Comment: I didn't realize that any name mangling happened, thanks for the solution!